# WebSocket loop establishes the connection

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I use Java language. The code of client are as follow:

```java
import javax.websocket.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static WebSocketClient client;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        client = new WebSocketClient();
        client.close();
    }
}
```

And the content of `WebSocketClient.java` is:

```java
import javax.websocket.*;
import java.io.IOException;

@ClientEndpoint
public class WebSocketClient implements AutoCloseable{

    private final Session session;

    public WebSocketClient() throws DeploymentException, IOException {
        String URI = "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws";
        this.session =
                ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer()
                        .connectToServer(WebSocketClient.class, java.net.URI.create(URI));
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session){
        System.out.println("Connection Established:" + session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable throwable){
        System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
    }


    public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
        this.session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
    }

    public void disconnect() throws IOException {
        this.session.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        this.session.close();
    }
}
```

Only 2 files in the project.
The content of `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocker-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I try to run this appliction. What I expected is when the connect established, the server will receive the request. The code of server when it handle the establishment is:

```java
package com.example.websocketserver;

import jakarta.websocket.OnClose;
import jakarta.websocket.OnMessage;
import jakarta.websocket.OnOpen;
import jakarta.websocket.Session;
import jakarta.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class WebSocketServer{
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session){
        System.out.println("Successfully establish the connection:" + session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String message){
        System.out.println("Received message from:" + session.getId() + ", content is:" + message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session){
        System.out.println("Connection closed:" + session.getId());
    }


}
```

The problem is: The server outputs lot of text of establishment of connection. I think the server is not the key of problem, because I transferred the client's connection establishment code directly to the `main` function and annotated the Main class with `@ClientEndpoint` (the corresponding logic has not changed), I can only establish a connection once, instead of establishing connections all the time, in cycles.

---

**So the problem is how can I encapsulate this logic into the creation of the WebSocketClient object and still ensure that only one connection is established?**